# SetActive. Объясните, почему не работает?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Вот есть код. Когда нажиму на клавишу, куб должен появляться, а когда отпускаю пропадать, но ничего не выходит.
Я проверял с помощью debug.log и часть где нажимается левая или правая кнопка мыши и выполняется действие - НЕ РАБОТАЕТ. Почему? Объясните пожалуйста.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class KillHit : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject hitb;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        hitb = GameObject.Find("killcube");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if(Input.GetMouseButton(0) || Input.GetMouseButton(1)){
            hitb.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }else{
            hitb.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            Debug.Log("Works1");
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if(other.gameObject.tag == "enemy01")   {
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вероятнее всего на момент запуска сцены ваш `"killcube"` уже отключен. Unity не может получать GameObject и его компоненты, если тот отключен `SetActive(false)`'

Чтобы всё заработало, вы должны заранее получить ссылку на ваш `GameObject hitb`.
Проще говоря, в начале получите ещё включённый `"killcube"`, а потом отключите его методом `SetActive(false)`.

А, и использование команды `GameObject.Find(string name)` не выгодно со стороны производительности, легче было перенести ваш объект напрямую в UnityEditor-е.

Answer (score -1):

```
 - Input.GetMouseButton - когда мышка нажата и удерживается в состоянии Down
 - Input.GetMouseButtonDown - когда клавиша опущена вниз
 - Input.GetMouseButtonUp - когда клавиша поднимается верх

void Update () {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1)){
            hitb.SetActive(true);
        }
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) || Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1)){
            hitb.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

p.s. 
public GameObject hitb;
Это и так GameObject, зачем еще раз вызывать .gameObject (hitb.gameObject.SetActive).
```